# concatenating fields in server tags in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to combine the first and last names and  present them in the repeater.
The following does not concatenate the string. How do i get this to work.

```
Text='<%#Eval("FirstName")%>' '<%Eval("LastName")%>'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %> <%# Eval("LastName") %>'
```

or

```
Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") + " " + Eval("LastName") %>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Text='<%#Eval("FirstName") & " " & Eval("LastName")%>' [for VB.Net]


Text='<%#Eval("FirstName") + " " + Eval("LastName")%>' [for C#.Net]
```